# Is it possible to change the black background color of android app drawer programmatically?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm working on an android apk in which the app drawer background is changed. I have searched through the internet. I have found 2 methods to change the app drawer's black background.

First one is using apktool, which decompiles launcher.apk and builds it back to apk format. In between the programmer do the required changes ( res/values/colors , background="..." ). Then sign and move it back to system/app folder.

Second one is using another application like GO Launcher, but I have to use my own application to change the black background color programmatically.

Is there a way to achieve this ( in eclipse for example ) ?

Thank you for your supports and answers in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example for your requirement (programatically):

```
    redBtn.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.d("MYAPP", "RED touched..");
            setActivityBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

The function defination for `setActivityBackgroundColor();` is given below:

```
public void setActivityBackgroundColor(int color) {
    View view = this.getWindow().getDecorView();
    view.setBackgroundColor(color);
}
```

This worked for me, you can modify same as per your requirement.

Accept the answer if it meets your requirement.

-Regards

Comment: Thanks for your reply Zax,

However, this didn't solve the problem. In my case I have a background application ( Background.apk ). When I implement the code you provide into this project's source file, this.getWindow() line returns the window of my application. 

On the other hand, I need to access the android's app drawer window, which is one of the sub windows of system launcher.apk application.